# Where in the address space are the dynamically linked libraries mapped?

Tags: linux, memory, process, linker, operating-system

Each process has a text section containing the instructions. If a program (an executable file) uses some static libraries, then the text section of each static library will be merged into the text section of the program.

What about the shared libraries? The text section of each shared library will be mapped into the text section of the process at run-time? If that's not the case then where (in which section of the process address space) are the shared libraries mapped?